# Laravel Route call via AJAX gets wrong URL 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following route defined in my web.php

```
Route::delete('/contributions/contribution/destroy', 'ContributionController@destroy');
```

In my blade file I have a button that when clicked displays a sweetalert to confirm deletion. This works correctly, but when the user presses the delete button instead of it going to the URL defined in Ajax it goes to an incorrect URL and logs the following error:

> jquery.min.js:4 DELETE http://localhost/contributions/batches/batch/edit 404 (Not Found)

Here is button code

```
<td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon btn-destroy" 
                                                    data-batch-id="{{ $batch->id }}" 
                                                    data-id="{{ $contribution->id }}" 
                                                    data-amount="${{ number_format ($contribution->contribution_amount, 2, '.', ',') }}"
                                                    data-contributor="{{ $contribution->first_name.' '.$contribution->last_name }}"
                                                ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                        </td>
```

Here is my script

```
<script>

$(document).on('click', '.btn-destroy', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var batchId = $(this).data('batch-id');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var amount = $(this).data('amount');
    var contributor = $(this).data('contributor');
    swal({
            title: "Delete?",
            text: "Do you want to delete contribution for "+ amount +" from "+ contributor +"?",
            type: "error",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
            confirmButtonText: "Delete",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/contributions/contribution/destroy') }}",
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                type: "DELETE",
                data: {batch:batchId, contribution:id},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    }               
            });
    });
});
```

oddly enough, refreshing the page after the error returns my session flash message from my controller's destroy function

*Note: I did add the DELETE verb to IIS, before this I was receiving:

> 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)

Any ideas?

Comment: After further review I have determined the error is coming from my return route in my controller's destroy function. The record is being deleted but on return it is trying to use the DELETE Method. Why is this? DELETE http://localhost/contributions/batches/batch/edit/CC396D30-1B2D-11E8-86CF-F17D66680D09 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of reading and wrenching I have a working solution:

route:

```
Route::delete('/contributions/contribution/destroy', 'ContributionController@destroy');
```

link html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon btn-destroy" 
      data-id="{{ $contribution->id }}" 
      data-amount="${{ number_format ($contribution->contribution_amount, 2, '.', ',') }}"
      data-contributor="{{ $contribution->first_name.' '.$contribution->last_name }}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

jquery/ajax:

```
<script>

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-destroy', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var contributionId = $(this).data('id');
        var amount = $(this).data('amount');
        var contributor = $(this).data('contributor');
        swal({
                title: "Delete?",
                text: "Do you want to delete contribution for "+ amount +" from "+ contributor +"?",
                type: "error",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
                confirmButtonText: "Delete",
                closeOnConfirm: false
            },
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    method: "DELETE",
                    url: "{{ url('/contributions/contribution/destroy') }}",
                    data: {contributionId:contributionId},
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if ( msg.status === 'success' ) {
                            swal("Deleted", msg.msg, "success");
                            setInterval(function() {
                                window.location.reload();
                            }, 3900);
                        }
                    },              
                    error: function(msg) {
                        swal("Error!", "Something went wrong.", "error");
                        console.log(msg.status);
                    }
                });
        });
    }); 

</script>
```

controller:

```
public function destroy(Request $request)

{
    if ( $request->ajax() ) {

        Contribution::find($request->contributionId)->delete();

        return response(['msg' => 'Entry deleted', 'status' => 'success']);
    }
    return response(['msg' => 'Failed deleting the entry', 'status' => 'failed']);        
}
```

Works perfectly!

[image: Delete swal]

[image: Confirmation]

Answer (score 1):

Try this style of ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('/contributions/contribution/destroy') }}",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
       'data':{
         '_method':'delete',
          '_token':'{{ csrf_token() }}',
       },
       'method':'post'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I removed the error by running simple classic:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

or you can launch that remotely. Create a route and a Controller and call it via browser link:

```
Route::get('/b/{x}',  'for_stuff\BController@kukuku');
```

and put into the controller's function:

```
Artisan::call('route:clear');
```

say:

https://mysite/b/r